# Model with 2 foreign keys with 2 navigation properties causes error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, properties, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I'm a newcomer to ASP.NET MVC and I got stuck with a trivial problem for hours. I have a simple class that models a message.

Here is my code:

```
public class Message
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // AspNetUsers
    public ApplicationUser Sender { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser Receiver { get; set; }

    // SenderId of the message
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Sender")]
    [Display(Name = "Sender")]
    [InverseProperty("MessageSenderId")]
    public string SenderId { get; set; }

    // ReceiverId of this message
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Receiver")]
    [Display(Name = "Receiver")]
    [InverseProperty("MessageReceiverId")]
    public string ReceiverId { get; set; }

    // other properties
}
```

The `SenderId` and `ReceiverId` are the `Id` of sender and receiver of this message respectively. The `Sender` and `Receiver` are navigation properties to fetch them from database when I want to pass the model to the view.

Unfortunately, when I want to add a new migration, this error is raised:

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Mails_dbo.AspNetUsers_ReceiverId". The conflict occurred in database "DbName", table "dbo.AspNetUsers", column 'Id'

***UPDATE***

The previous model of Message was:

```
public class Message
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // No Navigation is defined

    // SenderId of the message
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Sender")]
    public string SenderId { get; set; }

    // ReceiverId of this message
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Receiver")]
    public string ReceiverId { get; set; }

    // other properties
}
```

What have I done wrong? Thanks

Comment: Looks like you have existing data in `Mails` table with `ReceiverId` not matching any `Id` from `AspNetUsers` table.

Comment: The sender/receiver id of a message are id of a user in AspNetUser table. If i mess sth up with ReceiverId, Whats that?

Comment: I understand that. But according to the exception message, you are upgrading existing table called `Mails`. And the upgrade script cannot enforce the FK constraint due to existing data violating it. It would be nice if you provide more info, e.g. what was the previous model / table, what have you changed etc.

Comment: you should look at the ReceiverIds in the database and the ApplicationUser's. The exception suggests you have some ReceiverIds for which there is no ApplicationUser to be found, which might mean you have inconsistent data.

Comment: @IvanStoev I added previous Message class

Comment: @DevilSuichiro The sql statement for creating ReceiverId and SenderId is : 
  ` [SenderId]      NVARCHAR (MAX) DEFAULT ('') NOT NULL,
    [ReceiverId]    NVARCHAR (MAX) DEFAULT ('') NOT NULL,`

Comment: Open the SSMS and execute the following query `select M.* from Mails M left join AspNetUsers U on M.ReceiverId = U.Id where U.Id is null`. If it returns some records, then these are the records with `ReceiverId` value preventing the FK constraint.